# JavaScriptInterface only working with local HTML file

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have created an android application which uses a webview to access an HTML file. This was done to map 2 javascript functions to 2 native android functions using a JavaScriptInterface. These 2 functions bring up and dismiss the android soft keyboard.

When I originally tested the file, I was running it locally and it worked. Since then, I have placed the file on a server and changed the webview to access the HTML file through the server. Since placing it on the server, the javascriptinterface functions are no longer being called.

Is there a flag that needs to be set or a permission I am missing? I have searched to no avail.

here is the HTML code

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Login Page</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function capturePassword(event)
    {
        event = (event) ? event : window.event
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("password").focus();
        document.getElementById("password").click();

        }
    }
    function myFunction()
    {
        jsi.showKeyboard(); //this is a function in the webview android app which does not get called when the file is placed on the server
    }
    function hideKeyboardMaybe()
    {
        event = (event) ? event : window.event
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode == 13) {
            jsi.hideKeyboard(); //same here
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
      User name: <input type="number" id="fname" autofocus      onkeyup="capturePassword(event)"><br>
      Password: <input type="number" id="password" onfocus="myFunction()"     onkeyup="hideKeyboardMaybe(event)"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the webview code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final WebView mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
JavaScriptInterface jsi = new JavaScriptInterface(this, mWebView);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsi, "jsi"); 

//setContentView(mWebView);
mWebView.loadUrl("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +     "/sippopup.html");
mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

}


public class JavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;
WebView v;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
JavaScriptInterface(Context c, WebView v) {
mContext = c;
this.v=v;

}


@JavascriptInterface
public void showKeyboard()
{

InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(v, 0);

}

@JavascriptInterface
public void hideKeyboard()
{

InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

}
}



}
```

Comment: There ya go. All of this works when I access the html file from the sd card.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is disabled in WebViews by default, you will need to enable it in code.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have had that setting enabled. The desired functionality works when I access the HTML file locally, but not when it is accessed through the server.